# Excpetion Message: Insert String Representation of Faulty Value

Tags: c++, string, exception, casting

I want to throw an exception of type `domain_error` if `key` of type `T` is not a valid key.
But I don't know how I could convert any type `T` to a string, as long as `T::operator std::string()` is defined, as for instance `int` does not support this.

This is obvioulsy wrong, as it only works for very specific types:

```
throw std::domain_error("key error: "+static_cast<std::string>(key));
```

How can this be done?

## edit

My solution after the suggestion to use template specilisation

```
template <class T> std::string to_string(const T t)
    {
        return static_cast<std::string>(t);
    }

    template <> std::string to_string<unsigned int>(const unsigned int i)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        std::string ret;
        ss << i;
        ss >> ret;
        return ret;
    }
```

...

```
std::string domain_error(const IS& is) const
    {
        using namespace IDTranslator_detail;
        return "key error: "+to_string(is), "error";
    }
```

...

```
throw std::domain_error(domain_error(key));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done, as described, in 100% of all situations.

You must specify that a part of the contract for your template is that whatever class is passed as a parameter it must support `operator std::string`.

You could also write, as part of your contract, that numeric types would also be allowed, and you will implement this in your template, as a specialization that uses `std::to_string`.

For a robust implementation, in this situation I would use `SFINAE` to try `std::to_string`, `operator std::string`, and if both fail, use some bland label, like "unknown type" in the exception message. Maybe use `typeid` together with my compiler's demangler to, at least, get a C++ type name out of it.